# How to redirect user to another url on when windows load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below code but it's not working, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
    
 window.location = "http://www.youtube.com";
   } else {
   
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code shown works for me (not in the snippet because of mixed content http/https problems, but tested on its own it was fine). Which browser were you testing in, and do you see any errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly change your code to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
      location.href = "http://www.youtube.com";
   } else {
      location.href = "http://www.google.com";
   }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use **location.href** instead of **window.location**.

Comment: Why? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) you can set `location = "URL string"` and it should work the same as `location.href = ...`.

Comment: Just gave it a try in the console. I usually do location.href and it worked. I don't know which browser OP uses and I believe location.href will have the widest support. Overall it's just common approach for me. Thanks for sharing the link! Never too late to learn something new :)